# Django Models relations

Tags: python, django, django-models, models, relationships

Below is my Django models code

```
    from django.db import models


class BookUser(models.Model):
    email= models.CharField(max_length=254,primary_key=True)          #mail address key
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)                  #max 64 char (lower case?)
    contact= models.CharField(max_length=12)
    imei = models.CharField(max_length=16)                #imei number
    address= models.TextField()            #list of address ids
    booksInShelf:[]        #list of user book's unique ids
    booksUnderCirculation:[]     #list of user book's unique ids


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('email',)

class Book(models.Model):
    isbn = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description =models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    userRating = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    users =            #list of user ids hold this book in shelf

class UserBook(models.Model):
    #id:                    generated by django
    bookId:               #id of parent book
    rent= models.BooleanField(default=False)           #boolean is ready to rent
    sell= models.BooleanField(default=False)                    #boolean is ready to sell
    price =models.FloatField()              #selling price
    rentBase=models.FloatField()          #base price of rent
    rentPeriod=models.IntegerField()             #days after which extra rent would apply
    dateModified =models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)             #track date it came into shelf
    dateAdded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Here BookUser is the actual user who has some books in two categories i.e booksinShelf and bookUnderCirculation

class Book is central repository of all books, I need to define a one to many relation to BookUser.What is the easy way to do this?

User Book is specific to BookUser and it should be uniquely pointing to Class Book , So its many to one relation to Book Class.

I am confused on how to handle ids of UserBook and Book?
Also how to store the list of ids of UserBooks in class BookUser??

Comment: Hello @eagle06  your comments are confusing just beside your models please correct then you say you need OneToMany relationship to BookUser in your Book model but your comment says you might in need of ManyToMany , also in BookUser models your just specified the unique ids , but think twice you might need the full information of the Book, I have therefore framed my answer based on your explaination not on the comments in models, if so please edit the question and comment below my comment like update the question above tagging me.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the Models and explanation provided below the `Book` model the users field should have `ForeignKey` relationship with the `BookUser` model.

so Book model should look like

```
class Book(models.Model):
    isbn = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description =models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    userRating = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    users = models.ForeignKey(BookUser, null=True, blank=True)
```

if you are using Postgresql and if you just need the `pk` list of `booksInShelf` and `booksUnderCirculation` then your BookUser model should look like

```
class BookUser(models.Model):
    email= models.CharField(max_length=254,primary_key=True)                 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)                  
    contact= models.CharField(max_length=12)
    imei = models.CharField(max_length=16)                
    address= models.TextField()            
    booksInShelf = models.ArrayField(models.IntegerField())        
    booksUnderCirculation = models.ArrayField(models.IntegerField())
```

and if you wish to have the full information of `booksInShelf` and `booksUnderCirculation` (not just the `pk` but other information related to the book as well), then you need to define it as `ManyToMany` relation.

```
class BookUser(models.Model):
        email= models.CharField(max_length=254,primary_key=True)                 
        name = models.CharField(max_length=254)                  
        contact= models.CharField(max_length=12)
        imei = models.CharField(max_length=16)                
        address= models.TextField()            
        booksInShelf = models.ManyToMany(UserBook)
        booksUnderCirculation = models.ManyToMany(UserBook)
```

also rather than creating two ManyToMany fields in the BookUser model you can have two flags in your UserBook model called `is_in_shelf` and `is_under_circulation`. These fields would be BooleanField, you can check more about the model fields in Django Documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#fields

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want :

```
class UserBook(models.Model):
    bookId = models.ForeignKey('Book')
```

Here a `UserBook` has a reference to a `Book` item, and severals users can have the same book, but it's still a unique reference in you table Book.

Hope it helps